# Error executing MySQL query from an Arduino

Tags: mysql, sql, arduino

I'm using the following code:

```
void setup() {
   mySerial = new Serial( this, "COM8", 115200 );
   output = createWriter( "data.txt" );
   msql = new MySQL( this, "localhost", "arduino", "root","" );
   if ( msql.connect() )
    {output.println("connected");}
    else{output.println("not connected");}
  // output = open( "data.txt" );
}
void draw() {
    if (mySerial.available() > 0 ) {
      int d = day();
      int m = month();
      int y = year();

      int s = second();  // Values from 0 - 59
      int min = minute();  // Values from 0 - 59
      int h = hour();

      String a = String.valueOf(d);
      String b = String.valueOf(m);
      String c = String.valueOf(y);
         String value = mySerial.readString();
         if ( value != null ) {
              output.print( value );
              String state=value;
              String x=a+"/"+b+"/"+c;
              String z=h+":"+min+":"+s;
              output.println(x);
              output.println(z);
              msql.execute( "INSERT INTO info(status,date,time) VALUES ("+state+","+x+","+z+");" );

         }
    }
```

But receive this error:

> Error: Using driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 3.1 SQL.query():
>   java.sql.SQLException.
>
> INSERT INTO info(status,date,time) VALUES (No detect
>   ,20/3/2015,20:7:23); java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'detect ,20/3/2015,20:7:23)'
>   at line 1

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Install MySQL Workbench (I think it's called) and try the insert manually. You need single quotes around the values and also SQL compliant date / time formats.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with electronic design.

Comment: This is in urgent need of [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/). That this works will be a complete fluke.